# Expanding a difficult formula using ARRAYFORMULA while avoiding circular references (Google Sheets)

Tags: arrays, google-sheets, vlookup, offset

I'm trying to set up a formula in Google Sheets that does this...

```
=IF(IFERROR(INDEX(Matches!$L$2:$L,MATCH($A2&(B$1-14),Matches!$H$2:$H&Matches!$M$2:$M,0)))=1,
IFERROR(OFFSET($A$1,INDEX(Matches!$I$2:$I,MATCH($A2&(B$1-14),Matches!$H$2:$H&Matches!$M$2:$M,0)),COLUMN()-1)-(1/(2*($A2)^2))),
$A2)
```

That is to say, IF(match was won, take the current period's rank of your defeated opponent and do math to it, else show last period's rank).

But I want to set it into an ARRAYFORMULA so that it will expand automatically. What I have is this (and it doesn't work):

```
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A&($B$1:$1-14),{Matches!$H$2:$H&Matches!$M$2:$M,Matches!$L$2:$L},2,0))=1,
OFFSET($A$1,VLOOKUP($A$2:$A&($B$1:$1-14),{Matches!$H$2:$H&Matches!$M$2:$M,Matches!$I$2:$I},2,0),SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA($B$1:$1),2,1))-(1/(2*($A$2:$A)^2)),
$A$2:$A))
```

What it should look like is this:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Ui3nE.png

How it actually comes out is:

https://i.stack.imgur.com/tQOl7.png

All of those errors are the same message, which is that VLOOKUP couldn't find 143997, which is just the first value pair. I've tried using VLOOKUP/MATCH, but it produces a circular reference error.

Is this possible? I'm willing to believe it's not, but I thought I should ask. Thanks for any help you can offer.

Comment: share a copy of your sheet

Comment: Please do consider of sharing a [test sheet](https://webapps.stackexchange.com/a/138383/117311)

Comment: Sorry for the delay. I got around to doing this.

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/e/2PACX-1vSX_CPCAaIXIAFwjjiJGvUotS_IPrB8YSUFHs2j-3sHHj-7EvuVfSXO3zkKGgdqThJGjdFfP23KWVkF/pubhtml

The RQ, NewRQ, and Rank tabs are the working, non ARRAYFORMULA versions of RQArr, NewRQArr, and RankArr. If you can come up with a way of making any of those three ARRAYFORMULA versions work, I'd be most grateful. I've hit a wall.

Comment: Sorry, that link doesn't let you see the formulas. Use this: 

https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1cJ7drj7AFAGUtYUwm6FqDt3ybJKNnJQTTki1pfjrvn0/edit?usp=sharing

Answer (score 0):

You can't use that `OFFSET` formula within `ARRAYFORMULA`. When the `VLOOKUP` throws an error the `OFFSET` is not able to handle it. That's why it won't work. You should apply your math on the output of the `VLOOKUP`.

Comment: In this case the math is outside both VLOOKUP functions. I've successfully used OFFSET within ARRAYFORMULA before. Is it the way I'm using it?

Comment: I am sorry for the unclear answer. I edited it. If you have a way to apply the math directly to the `VLOOKUP` output it will work.

Comment: Just so that I understand it, do you know why the VLOOKUP throws errors in that context? It doesn't seem like it should.

Comment: This equivalent formula throws a circular reference error, by the way:
=ARRAYFORMULA(IF(IFERROR(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A&($B$1:$1-14),{Matches!$G$2:$G&Matches!$L$2:$L,Matches!$K$2:$K},2,0))=1,
VLOOKUP(VLOOKUP($A$2:$A&($B$1:$1-14),{Matches!$G$2:$G&Matches!$L$2:$L,Matches!$H$2:$H},2,0),$A$2:$G,SEQUENCE(1,COUNTA($B$1:$1),2,1),1)-(1/(2*($A$2:$A)^2)),
$A$2:$A))

Comment: It does because there isn't a match for each lookup. That will throw an error and the OFFSET function expects a numeric value to work with.